# RequestBody passed MultiparFile is empty

Tags: spring, rest, postman

I'm trying to pass a list of files in a Post request as follow:

**PostMan:**

[image]

**Controller:**

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Upload documents in the GED")
@PostMapping(consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void uploadFileHandler(@ModelAttribute DocumentsUploadForm documentsUploadForm, @RequestBody List<MultipartFile> documents,
        @RequestParam("easy") String easy) throws BusinessException, IOException, CrsPermissionViolationException {
    .... 
    ....
}
```

All passed parameters and variables are not null, only the List of the MultipartFile documents is empty.

Any idea please?

Kind regards,

Comment: Is it work with a single file @RequestBody MultipartFile documents ? Try to place your file to zip archive.

Comment: @ValeriyK. i test it but the file object was null

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me for multiple files from POSTMAN.

**Note:** Please take care of conventions and null checks.

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public void uploadFileHandler(@RequestBody List<MultipartFile> documents, @RequestParam("easy") String easy)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println(easy);
    if(documents != null && !documents.isEmpty()) {
        for(MultipartFile file : documents) {
            storeFile(file);
        }
    }
}

public void storeFile(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println(fileName);
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(new File("C://Users//username//Desktop//upload//"+fileName)));
        stream.write(bytes);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

[image: POSTMAN Request]

Comment: I used the same code but the list is empty. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: On a side note. Don't add any headers in the POSTMAN request. Just add form-data. Postman will take care of it.